# Springboot Updating an Attribute without returning a page or redirect?

Tags: spring-boot, attributes

im making my own Java version of javascripts eventhandler on change. I have this method to add all the attributes on the page load:

```
@GetMapping("/hamtaleads")
    public String showLeadsPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("count", "1");
        return "hamtaleads";

    }
```

I am setting the attribute to "1", in thymeleaf i set the element with this code:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center" th:text="${count}" id="resultShow"></h1>
```

The element shows 1, as it should.

Because the user is filling a form, i have created a void method below, to update an element everytime the user does something. Everytime a user does something it submits a form ( homemade on-change event) linked to /change

The on change event works, however i want to update the element when a user does something with the code beow

```
@GetMapping("/change")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void funnyMethod(@RequestParam(value="valueToSubmit", required = false) String query, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("count", "10");
        System.out.println(query);
    }
```

It prints out "query" variable everytime the user presses a button, as it should, but it does not update my h1 element to "10" through the attribute "count". It stays as 1.

I do not want to redirect the page because the form will reset, it want the h1 element to change everytime the user does something, change to "10" but it stays as "1" as i set it on page load...

Is there anyway i can update this h1 element without redirecting the page?

Note: I cannot use Javascript for this because i a mysql connection, i have tried for 10 hours to get mysql to work in js but i have given up that method. I wont go to sleep before i get this to work

Comment: You don't have to write your MySQL in JavaScript in the first place. Instead of creating Controller you can use RestController to create REST endpoints and youll get result in JSON (You have to use Controller and RestController In different Controller Java file). You can use JavaScript AJAX calls to call your REST controller and get response in real time without reloading page.

Comment: Thanks Akash, i will look into AJAX :)